# Creating textures for other programs

Tags: texturing, shaders

I created a chain mail with blender. I would like to be able to export only texture images (like BaseColor, Diffuse, Metalness, Normals, Roughness) without 3d object, to use them in other programs like Daz or Marvelous. How can I do? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will have to switch to cycles, select your object, and bake any one of the following:[image] See some tutorials about how to bake in blender.